# grid.setFilter(null); how to supprress warning

Tags: javascript, dojo

In my application I want to set my filter plugin for my enhanced grid to null or to something else with

```
grid.setFilter([{
    type: 'string',
    column: 1,
    condition: 'contains',
     value: 'Test'
    }, {
    type: 'number',
    column: 2,
    condition: 'lessthan',
    value: 100
    }], 'logicany');
}
```

or

```
grid.setFilter(null);
```

programmatically. When I have set more than one filter rule, dojo pops up a warning message. It asks whether I am sure to clear the filter. My question is: How can I suppress this warning? Can I? Do I have to change the Filter.js of dojo? Or is there a way to click the button somehow programmatcally as last way of workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use

`grid.clearFilter()`

Also take a look at this file: [FilterDefDialog.js](https://github.com/dojo/dojox/blob/master/grid/enhanced/plugins/filter/FilterDefDialog.js#L1127)

```
onClearFilter: function(e){
        // summary:
        //      Triggered when the "Clear" button is clicked.
        if(this._savedCriterias){
            if(this._savedCriterias.length >= this.plugin.ruleCountToConfirmClearFilter){
                this.plugin.clearFilterDialog.show();
            }else{
                this.clearFilter(this._clearWithoutRefresh);
            }
        }
    }
```

Just use clear, rather than setFilter.

Comment: Look to see where the confirmation dialog saves itself to. Have a look through the source.